# convert my sql query to queryexpression or fetchxml in crm

Tags: mysql, fetchxml, query-expressions

I have this `SQL` query where I am trying to fetch the `opportunityId` from opportunity entity for whom `approvaldocument`  has not been created (approval document is the name of the other entity) .I dont think fetchxml supports such kind of query. I am new to crm and my project is in `crm 4.0` version.

here's the sql query:

```
Select OpportunityId from opportunity AS c left JOIN (select a.opportunitynameid from opportunity o
JOIN ApprovalDocument a ON 
a.opportunitynameid=o.OpportunityId) AS b ON c.OpportunityId=b.opportunitynameid
Where b.opportunitynameid IS NULL and statecode=0
```

I converted this into a `fetchxml`, but that didn't give the correct result.

```
<fetch version="1.0" output-format="xml-platform" mapping="logical" distinct="true"> 
    <entity name="opportunity"> <attribute name="opportunityid" /> 
       <link-entity name="approvaldocument" from="opportunitynameid" to="opportunityid" alias="a" link-type="outer"> <attribute name="opportunitynameid" /> 
       </link-entity> 
       <filter type="and"> 
          <condition entityname="a" attribute="opportunitynameid" operator="null" /> 
       </filter> 
    </entity> 
<fetch/>
```

Comment: <fetch version="1.0" output-format="xml-platform" mapping="logical" distinct="true">
  <entity name="opportunity">
    <attribute name="opportunityid" />
    <link-entity name="approvaldocument" from="opportunitynameid" to="opportunityid" alias="a" link-type="outer">
       <attribute name="opportunitynameid" />
    </link-entity>
    <filter type="and">
        <condition entityname="a" attribute="opportunitynameid" operator="null" />
    </filter>
  </entity>
<fetch/>

Answer (score 0):

Natively it is not possible to create an advanced find to query for the absence of a relationship.  However there are several different solutions for achieving this functionality:

**Workaround:**
Create a marketing list with the full set of records and then remove records using the inverse of your condition.  The steps for doing this are nicely laid out in [this article.](http://www.powerobjects.com/2009/05/04/accounts-with-no-contacts-and-fun-with-subqueries/)

**Modifying FetchXML and Third Party Solutions:**
Although the advanced find cannot show "Not In" results, the underlying FetchXML does support this functionality.  An example of manually building such Fetch is [shown here](http://debajmecrm.com/2014/08/27/left-join-with-not-in-operator-in-microsoft-dynamics-crm-2013/).  Also there are several third party tools which leverage this ability to provide Not In functionality directly in the advanced find. The best solution I am aware of is [available here](http://www.cobalt.net/cobaltintelligentquery?__hssc=164285792.1.1457871227916&__hstc=164285792.358d0651ac458462cae1b429f678f915.1456407871323.1456407871323.1457871227916.2&__hsfp=1848569343&hsCtaTracking=5437997c-2ce1-43e0-9f7b-e13f209e5d9c%7C92732bb7-ba40-4618-a936-9d1f1a5e392a).

Comment: Can anyone help me converting it to a stored procedure or a query expression