# converting sql query into a stored proc

Tags: stored-procedures

```
Select OpportunityId 
from opportunity AS c 
    left JOIN (
        select a.opportunitynameid 
        from opportunity o
            JOIN ApprovalDocument a ON a.opportunitynameid=o.OpportunityId
    ) AS b ON c.OpportunityId=b.opportunitynameid
Where b.opportunitynameid IS NULL and statecode=0
```

Comment: What part of pasting that into a stored procedure is troubling you?

Comment: I imagine the syntax and examples of the `CREATE PROCEDURE` command is something that can be easily found on Google.  Where specifically are you stuck?  What have you tried that isn't working?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [convert my sql query to queryexpression or fetchxml in crm](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35955040/convert-my-sql-query-to-queryexpression-or-fetchxml-in-crm)

Answer (score 0):

```
Create Procedure mySP_GetOpportunity
@statuscode int = 0
As
Select OpportunityId 
from opportunity AS c left JOIN 
    ( select a.opportunitynameid from opportunity o JOIN ApprovalDocument a ON a.opportunitynameid=o.OpportunityId ) AS b 
    ON c.OpportunityId=b.opportunitynameid 
Where b.opportunitynameid IS NULL 
and statecode=@statuscode
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the sql query between 
    `CREATE PROCEDURE Proc_Name
    AS
    "query goes here"
    GO`

for more detail refer [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms345415.aspx)