# Entity Views - Multiple Conditions

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I want to create a View For Account entity which will show me the accounts with "No Appointments" as well as the accounts with "No Appointments in Last 6 months".

Actually I need a view which will display those accounts which have no appointments at all as well as those appointments having no appointments since last 6 months.

Is it possible?

Comment: Can you elaborate on how the union of "No Appointments" and "No Appointments in Last 6 months" would be different from just "No Appointments"? Additionally, what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Views in Dynamic CRM are built on **FetchXML** queries. This query language does support left outer joins, *but* it is not possible to filter the result set to just the rows where there is no match on the right side.

So, the answer to your question is "no"; given a 1:n relationship it is not possible to create a view showing only rows from the 1-side with no associated data on the n-side.

Answer (score 0):

Henks answer is incorrect.  FetchXML does support this behavior, it just isn't exposed natively in the advanced find.  For a full answer please reference [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35955040/convert-my-sql-query-to-queryexpression-or-fetchxml-in-crm/35970310#35970310)

Answer (score 0):

You can customise your `fetchxml` to have your requested result.

This should be something like this

```
    <fetch mapping='logical'>
 <entity name='account'>
  <attribute name='name'/>
  <link-entity name='appointment'
               from='activityid'
               to='accountid'
               link-type='outer'/>
  <filter type='or'>
   <condition entityname='appointment'
              attribute='activityid'
              operator='null'/>
            <filter type="and">
        <condition entityname='appointment' attribute="actualend" operator="last-x-months" value="6" />
        <condition entityname='appointment' attribute="statecode" operator="eq" value="1" />
      </filter>
  </filter>
```

I didn't tested but that give you what you asked, you can build a custom view with that or manipulate your `gridview`.

Otherwise you could also use a report to give you this information.